# telerik rad grid drag and drop reordering position indication

Tags: c#, drag-and-drop, telerik, radgrid

I have implemented telerik rad grid drag and drop reordering. please [take a look at this article](http://www.telerik.com/help/wpf/dragdropmanager-howto-draganddrop-within-radgridview.html).

I want to indicate the user where he is dropping the row. This article shows the wpf implementation of rad grid.

i am working in web forms application. wpf grid seems to have the attached behavior property but i am not able to find it in normal web forms application.

So if i want to achieve it in the web forms application then how can i achieve this  ?

This article shows that we can attach the behavior using the following code.

`void radGridView_DataLoaded(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    RowReorderBehavior.SetIsEnabled(this.radGridView, true);
}`

but it is not available on web forms. So is it just a WPF behavior ? or i can achieve in web forms application also ?

This image shows what i want to achieve.

[image: This image shows the row drop position indicator that i want in my rad grid]

Comment: The link you provided has the code for C#.

Comment: @SyedFarjadZiaZaidi yes but it is using xaml code. and i am not able to get the RowReorderBehavior.SetIsEnabled(this.radGridView, true); in my rad gridview

Comment: @SachinTrivedi Can you please try to link the above mentioned `radGridView_DataLoaded` handler to the event `DataLoaded` of your grid. I have tried this in WPF and works perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

In the XAML link the event handler 'radGridView_DataLoaded' to the event 'DataLoaded'

```
<telerik:RadGridView x:Name="SampleGrid"
                     ItemsSource="{Binding SampleObjects,Mode=TwoWay}"
                     HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"     
                     ShowColumnHeaders="True"
                     AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                     CanUserSortColumns="False" 
                     DataLoaded="radGridView_DataLoaded">
```

After this in the code behind include the event handler:

```
void radGridView_DataLoaded(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    RowReorderBehavior.SetIsEnabled(this.rgvFSCaptions, true);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The sample you have will only work for WPF.

The Dependency Properties and Behaviours from WPF do not exist in ASP.NET.